# How to use variables with .Values in helm template

Tags: go-templates, kubernetes-helm

I have the following values.yaml:

```
vrIds:
  - 51
  - 52
51.vip: 169.254.1.1
52.vip: 169.254.1.2
```

I have the following template:

```
{{ range $index, $element := .Values.vrIds }}
  vrrp.{{$element}}.vip: <<How do I get the value of $element.vip>>
{{ end }}
```

How do I get the value of $element.vip for each vrid?

Answer (score 12):

You need to modify your `values.yaml` a little:

```
vrIds:
  51: 169.254.1.1
  52: 169.254.1.2
```

And use the following construction inside your template files:

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.vrIds }}
  vrrp.{{ $key }}.vip: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: The problem is I have another parameter for each **VRID**.

`vrIds:
  - 51
  - 52
51.vip: 169.254.1.1
52.vip: 169.254.1.2
51.master: node-1
52.master: node-2`

Comment: This answer did the trick for me. I didn't see this listed in the documentation.